# Can you exceed power rating on a UPS with additional battery packs

Tags: electrical-power, ups

After reporting the wattage of a remote site that doesn't have a UPS to my boss he cc'd me on the quote for what he was going to order.  The site's networking and server equipment are using over 2,000 watts.  But he spec'd out a 1500v UPS with multiple battery packs to fulfill the long uptime necessary.  But my understanding is that if the equipment was to be plugged into the UPS it wouldn't be able to output enough power to the equipment, even though it would have multiple battery packs.  This is the first time I've been involved with the purchasing of UPSs (even though he decided the manufacturer and model) and we're a poorer school district so I want to make sure we aren't setting ourselves up for failure.  We only have 15 amp circuits so I know we can't go to a 2000v unit but wouldn't we need two 1500v units?

Thank you.

Comment: A 1,500VA UPS probably can't even supply 1,500 watts. A typical 1500 UPS cannot supply more than 900 watts.

Comment: Be careful with your units. You consistently wrote "v" where you should have written "VA" - a fundamental difference. It's not voltage but wattage you are concerned about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Wattage and VA rating of the UPS represents the load that the UPS can protect.

The battery and expansion packs only exist to increase the runtime of the UPS.

I would suggest multiple 2200VA UPS units with the batteries necessary to satisfy your runtime requirement.

The UPS manufacturer would gladly help you right-size the equipment and determine the proper solution.